# Concat SQL in Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to create a table that shows the concatenation of two fields from mysql and put it into one (table) field in java.

```
 pst = connection.prepareStatement("select patientId,concat(pFirstname,' ', pLastname), pAge, pAddress from infopatient");
```

This is the error that I've received but I have pFirstname and pLastname in my database.

> *java.sql.SQLException: Column 'concat(pFirstname,' ',pLastname)' not found.*

Comment: Add alias to this expression.

Comment: Just a guess: You might have to give that a name: `CONCAT(...) AS some_name`

Comment: Please post a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.  First, you can just access your result set using ordinal numbers, for example:

```java
pst = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT patientId, CONCAT(pFirstname, ' ', pLastname), pAge, pAddress FROM infopatient");
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String fullName = rs.getString(2);  // access second column of your select
}
```

The other option, as hinted to in the comments, would be to just give an alias to the concatenated field, e.g.

```java
String sql = "SELECT patientId, CONCAT(pFirstname, ' ', pLastname) AS fullName, pAge, pAddress FROM infopatient"
pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String fullName = rs.getString("fullName");  // access via alias
}
```

I generally prefer the second option, because it is more intuitive, readable, and also it is robust should the order of the select ever change (while the first version is not).

Comment: 1st option is not safe. If none alias assigned then the expression text is used as an alias which may result in a problem (which sometimes may be located hardly) in unpredictable moment in the code which may look like absolutely unrelative.

Comment: @Akina No, in the first case the order of the select list shouldn't depend on whether or not there is an alias.  As I have pointed out, option #2 is preferable, because if someone refactors the select in option #1, it could inadvertently break the code.

Comment: *in the first case the order of the select list shouldn't depend on whether or not there is an alias.* I tell nothing about this. I mean that without an alias the column name contains the symbols which are not legal in object names, and this may result in a problem. OP meets with the problem which occures immediately and in obvious point - but on another cases it may occur in some exotic place.

Comment: Oh...I hadn't thought of that, good point.  Another reason to use the alias version.